# Dynamic Textures

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, image-processing, image-segmentation

i know that texture refers to surface characteristics and appearance of an object given by the size, shape, density, arrangement, proportion of its elementary parts.

**But i am more interested in dynamic textures.**
 Can anyone give me information about what are Dynamic Textures?

**also in papers it is written that they exhibits some stationarity properties. but what do you mean by the stationarity property regarding dynamic textures?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dynamic texture is a texture that is a function of *space and time*. In Image Synthesis papers, it is a term often used to designate things like:

- a flame,
- a waving flag,
- specular reflections on water.

You can see some classic examples [here](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/cpl/projects/graphcuttextures/).